# How to get Selenium drivers to work with G1ANT / Windows 7?

Tags: selenium, windows-7, g1ant

Here is the one-line G1ANT script (not counting Add-ons):

```
addon selenium version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

selenium.open type firefox url ‴https://www.autohotkey.com‴
```

[image: Cannot start geckodriver]

But it IS started, and listening:

[image: It is started]

The platform is Win7 Pro 64-bit SP1; G1ANT version is 4.102.1. Driver is stock. If started from the command line, geckodriver.exe will start and listen on any unoccupied port (that I've tried, anyway).

Is this possibly my error? Is the error with G1ANT? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in G1ANT and it will be fixed soon. Currently there is no way to use Firefox with selenium addon but you can use Chrome browser instead.

```
addon selenium version 4.101.0.0
addon core version 4.101.0.0
addon language version 4.103.0.0

selenium.open type chrome url ‴https://www.autohotkey.com‴
```

Comment: As an update, the code you provided works for me on my Win7 platform, but only _sometimes_. I frequently (if not in fact most of the time) get the same symptoms as with geckodriver, i.e. the driver is actually started and listening although G1ANT reports it can't be started. Selenium does, however, work for me as expected from Python 3.7.